# output different plots based on user input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `selectInput` gadget asking the user to select a y axis. The options are Genre, Experience, and Rating, and I would like to output one of three bar plots i have created (ratebars3, expbars3, and genbars4). Each plot has the same x axis (company) but the graphs vary based on whatever the y is. Here is the code for the select input in my UI:

```
    selectInput("selecty", label = h3("Select Y axis"),
    choices = list("Rating", "Experience", "Genre"))
```

I have been trying some `if.. return` type statements in the server with no luck. If anyone would know some server code that could display my plots based on what the user inputs, that would be a huge help.

Comment: Are `Rating, Experience, and Genre` all columns in the same dataframe?

Comment: Yes they are, and I used that same dataframe to create my three bar plots

Comment: What sort of graphics are you using, `ggplot2`, `base`, or something else?

Answer (score 5):

I was using the `plotly` package but it seems that I've answered my own question. 
I had to create a **reactive** expression:

Server:

```
    barplottest <- reactive({
    if ( "Rating" %in% input$selecty) return(bars3)
    if ( "Experience" %in% input$selecty) return(expbars3)
    if( "Genre" %in% input$selecty) return(genbars4) 
    })

   output$barplot <- renderPlotly({   
   dataplots = barplottest()
   print(dataplots)
   })
```

Ui

```
      selectInput("selecty", label = h3("Select Y axis"),
                   choices = list("Rating", "Experience", "Genre")),
       plotlyOutput("barplot")
```

Comment: Looks good- As you've discovered, any time you want output to change, you'll need to have a reactive involved in some way

Comment: I appreciate your help!