# Create bargraph based purely on user input

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a very simple app to show census questions to test my understanding of `shiny`.
I can create an app using a datatable but I want to learn to create an app where plots of graphs are created based on purely user inputs. In the following app, the only problem is creating a bar plot that shows the number of children put in by the responder. That is, if the responder has 5 children, I expect the bar plot to be taller than if lets say, he selected he had 3 children.

First trial was as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

#define ui ----------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(
    inputId = "first_name", 
    label = "What is your first name? "),
  
  textOutput(
    outputId = "name"),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "university", 
    label = "Have you gone to university? (answer Yes/No): ", 
              choices = c("Yes", "No"), width = "100%"),
  
  numericInput(
    inputId = "children", 
    label = "How many children do you have? ", 
    value =  0, 
    min = 0, 
    max = NA),
  
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "wall_type", 
    label = "What is the wall material of your shelter? ", 
               choices =c("Timber", 
                          "Bricks", 
                          "Iron sheets", 
                          "Stone")),
  textAreaInput(
    inputId = "Livelihood", 
    label = "What has been your major source of livelihood in the past two weeks? ", 
                rows = 5),
  
  textOutput(
    outputId = "livelihood"),
  
  column(
    6, 
    plotOutput(
      outputId = "dependants", 
      width =  "100%"))
)

#define server ----------------------
server <- function(input, output, session){
  dep_plot <- reactive({input$children})
  
  output$name <- renderText(paste0(expr = "Hello ", input$first_name, " today!"))
  output$livelihood <- renderText(paste0(expr = "Looks like your major work is ", input$Livelihood))
  
  output$dependants <- renderPlot({
    input$children
  })
}

#create shiny app ------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This stack overflow - [output different plots based on user input in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750446/output-different-plots-based-on-user-input-in-shiny) question is closest to my objective. So I followed the methods.

Second trial

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

#define ui ----------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(
    inputId = "first_name", 
    label = "What is your first name? "),
  
  textOutput(
    outputId = "name"),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "university", 
    label = "Have you gone to university? (answer Yes/No): ", 
    choices = c("Yes", "No"), width = "100%"),
  
  numericInput(
    inputId = "children", 
    label = "How many children do you have? ", 
    value =  0, 
    min = 0, 
    max = NA),
  
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "wall_type", 
    label = "What is the wall material of your shelter? ", 
    choices =c("Timber", 
               "Bricks", 
               "Iron sheets", 
               "Stone")),
  textAreaInput(
    inputId = "Livelihood", 
    label = "What has been your major source of livelihood in the past two weeks? ", 
    rows = 5),
  
  textOutput(
    outputId = "livelihood"),
  
  column(
    6, 
    plotlyOutput(
      outputId = "dependants", 
      width =  "100%"))
)

#define server ----------------------
server <- function(input, output, session){
  #make response to no. of children reactive
  
  dep_plot <- reactive({input$children})
  
  output$name <- renderText(paste0(expr = "Hello ", input$first_name, " today!"))
  output$livelihood <- renderText(paste0(expr = "Looks like your major work is ", input$Livelihood))
  
  output$dependants <- renderPlotly({
    data = dep_plot()
    print(dep_plot())
  })
  }


#create shiny app ------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But there is no bargraph that is created based on how many children the user inputs. Could one show me how to go about it?
[image: children_number_barplot_missing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `input$children` inside a plotting function. For example,

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# define ui ----------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "children",
    label = "How many children do you have? ",
    value = 0,
    min = 0,
    max = NA
  ),
  column(
    6,
    plotOutput(
      outputId = "dependants",
      width = "100%"
    )
  )
)

# define server ----------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dep_plot <- reactive({
    data.frame(children = input$children)
  })
  
  output$dependants <- renderPlot({
    req(input$children)
    ggplot(dep_plot())+
      geom_col(aes(x = "1", y = children), width = 0.3) +
      labs(x = "Children", y = "count") +
      ylim(c(0, input$children + sample(3:5, 1))) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()
      )
  })
}

# create shiny app ------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hello @shafee, your code worked, but I would like to know how you can put the plotting function for `input$children` into `ggplot`. Here is an example but it's not working. Which nuance should I know to make it work. See snippet below.     ---------------------------------      ```output$dependants <- renderPlot({
    req(input$children)
    ggplot(dep_plot(), aes_string(x = input$first_name, y = input$children)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
  })
}``` .The server function remains as is.

Comment: @SamuelGachuhi, I have edited the code for `ggplot`. `ggplot` works with only `data.frame`, so you have to provide dataframe